# Remote DLNA / UPnP Media Client / Controller

Tags: remote, upnp, dlna

I have a MiniDLNA + Bubble UPnP Server running at home and I would like to access it remotely from my PC at work. I can check that the server is properly accessible though the Bubble UPnP App for Android, where I can enter the URL to my server.

There is a wide range of UPnP client software for Linux, but non of them offers the possibility to enter an URL, which is quite hard to believe. During my search I checked all of them listed [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients), and all of them just search the local network for servers.

Does anybody know a UPnP client / controller software which can deal with remote servers?

Answer (score 1):

DLNA/UPnP is not what you want for that. Fundamentally DLNA works using UPnP which broadcasts it's existance over the local network. That broacast signal wont fly over the wider internet.

You can either:

Use a VPN to connect your remote PC to the local network which contains the DLNA devices bypassing/ tunnelling through the internet such as open VPN [(on debian for example)](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/457103-install-and-configure-openvpn-server-on-linux) or PPTP [(also explempified by this how to for linux)](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)

Or:

Use some other internet capable streaming software such as [ampache](http://ampache.org/)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know, I am accessing my DLNA/UPnP server all the time at home from different devices, but I just would like to listen to some music at work every now and then. And the BubbleUPnP app on Android supports remote access of DLNA/UPnP server (which works like a charm) and there is other non-Linux software which can do that, too. So there are more than the two possibilities you are mentioning. I just cannot find any (free) software for linux which supports remote playback. The question is if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

BubbleUPnP Tether client is a simple Java command-line program that will make available on the LAN it is running Media Servers managed by BubbleUPnP Server on another LAN

[Bubble tether client](https://www.bubblesoftapps.com/bubbleupnpserver2/docs/connect_with_tether_client.html)

Answer (score -1):

Foobar2000 plus the foo_upnp plugin (written by bubblegum) if you're on a windows machine.  I use this to stream to my work laptop almost everyday.